# Setting printer password programmatically from C#

Tags: c#, printing

Is it possible to set printer password programmatically from C#?

Or is it at least possible to detect if a network printer is password protected, or in some other way prevent a password dialog from being displayed on the server running the program and instead return an error to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you should be able to extract the relevant part of [this example on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2316281/AddPrinterConnection-failing-to-add-network-printe.aspx)